# Is it best practice to use Vue component in blade template?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using multiple Vue components in Laravel blade template like below

```
<div id="app">
        <user-list></user-list>
        <first-component></first-component>
        <seconde-component>
            <h1>{{ $name }}</h1>
            <p>{{ $bio }}</p>
        </seconde-component>
</div>
```

I want to know if it's best practice to use Vue like this or not?  If 
not, what is best practice for using Vue components in Laravel?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has VueJS support [right out of the box.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend) You can you use any front-end library like AngularJS or ReactJS too inside if you Laravel app. According to the Laravel docs there is not a "best practice or method" to using VueJS in Laravel. It it just supported if you choose to use the library.

To help  your Laravel application you can setup a VueJS router for live loading, use ajax to get json from your laravel app without refreshing, est.